# A subobject is regarded as a proposition - internal logic

Tags: logic, category-theory, categorical-logic

> [a subobject $\ \phi\hookrightarrow A\ $ is regarded as a *proposition*: by thinking of it as the subcollection of all those things of type $A$ for which the statement $\phi$ is true](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic)

1. First of all I would have thought of a proposition at least as the class of all sub-objects with domain $\phi$, and this would still be weaker than the logician's notion of proposition. But let's accept this weak notion of proposition that nlab is giving. If someone wants to make a comment about it, more than welcome.
2. What troubles me the most is that there are possibly many monomorphisms $\phi\hookrightarrow A$ ---terms of type $A$ with a free variable of type $\phi$ with the usual quotient for the definition of sub-object that under this interpretation becomes alpha equivalence.

   What do these terms add to the interpretation of what the proposition ends up being?

   For instance, what's the difference between the two "propositions" $f(x) : [x:\phi] \hookrightarrow A$ and $g(x) : [x:\phi] \hookrightarrow A$, for $f$ and $g$ different function symbols.

I'm just starting to learn about this so I might be getting some stuff wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand your (2), but re: (1) the idea is to consider $A$ as a collection of things and $\phi\hookrightarrow A$ as picking out those which satisfy a particular property. For example, $\top$ is trivially satisfied by everything, so $\top$ should correspond to all of $A$; similarly, $\perp$ should correspond to none of $A$. (Stepping from category theory to first-order logic, think about how each sentence in FOL corresponds to a class of structures; e.g. in the language $\{*\}$, the sentence $\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)$ picks out the commutative magmas.)

Comment: The difference between $f(x)\colon [x:\phi]\hookrightarrow A$ and $g(x)\colon [x:\phi]\hookrightarrow A$ is that the first expresses the proposition $(\exists x:\phi)\, f(x) = y$, while the second expresses the proposition $(\exists x:\phi)\, g(x) = y$ (both are propositions with the same free variable $y$ of type $A$).

Comment: @AlexKruckman thanks for the comment. I have a question regarding your interpretation which was very illuminating by the way. I understand that a monomorphism is a term that "uses its free variable". So for instance once we go up to the category of contexts, we could say a proposition like "$c=y$", but we can't have propositions with empty quantifications like "$(\exists x:\phi)c=y$". This is because the term $c$ isn't a monomorphism in the context $[x:\phi]$, but it is in the empty context $[\ ]$. (Which again, exists in the category of contexts, not in general.) Am I missing something?

Comment: @Julián I'm afraid I don't understand your comment - "A monomorphism is a term that 'uses its free variable'" doesn't make any sense to me. Certainly there are terms that use their free variables but aren't monomorphisms (like $x^2$ when $x$ is an integer). But the correct way to generalize my comment is this: in a context where we have good epi-mono factorizations (e.g., a regular category), any arrow $f\colon A\to B$ has an epi-mono factorization into $e\colon A\to I$ and $m\colon I\to B$. Then $[m]$ as a subobject of $B$ has the interpretation $\exists (x:A) f(x) = y$.

Comment: In your case, you were assuming $f$ and $g$ were monic, so the above applies directly to the subobjects $[f]$ and $[g]$. Regarding empty quantifications, what is "allowed" will depend on choices of logical formalism, but there is certainly a way to make sense of $(\exists x : \phi) c = y$ in the internal language: view $c$ as a term with free variable $x$ by considering the map $\phi\to A$ obtained by composing the unique map $\phi\to 1$ to the terminal object with the constant map $c\colon 1\to A$, then take the image of this map in the sense of epi-mono factorization.

Comment: @AlexKruckman > Certainly there are terms that use their free variables but aren't monomorphisms like $x^2$ ; ; this is what I understand: we are working with intentional equality. Let's unfold the definition of monomorphism for this particular term $x^2:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$. For any sort $\sigma$ and parallel terms $u,v:\sigma\rightarrow\mathbb N$ we want "$x^2\circ u = x^2\circ v$ implies $u=v$". But these equalities hold at the syntactic level. $x^2\circ u$ is actually $x^2\ [x:=u]$. And if it's syntactically equal to $x^2\ [x:=v]$ I don't see a way in which $u\neq v$. Is this ok?

Comment: (Else if you don't use your free variable, the substitution becomes trivial, and no matter what $u\neq v$ you choose, composed with a constant term gives the constant term.)

On the other hand I really like your idea of using epi-mono factorization (if available). Thanks. :D

Comment: @Julián Oh, I see. Yes, if you're working with intentional equality, then I agree.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I just wanted to make a final comment, which just came to me. I find a striking similarity between the terms of the form $(\exists x:\phi) f(x)=y$ and the objects of the slice category $A/y$. It seems like we are getting close to ("discovering"/recovering) the definition of hyperdoctrine this way, as some kind of categorification of the interpretation of internal logic. Thoughts or comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we define subobjects of $A$ not as monomorphisms $\phi \hookrightarrow A$, but as *equivalence classes* of such monomorphisms. Intuitively we should identify two monomorphisms with the same image in $A$.

Precisely, say that $(\phi : X \to A) \leq (\psi : Y \to A)$ if and only if there is an arrow $f : X \to Y$ so that $\phi = \psi f$. Intuitively this says that the image of $\phi$ is contained in the image of $\psi$. Then we quotient the category of monos into $A$ by the equivalence relation where $\phi \sim \psi$ if and only if $\phi \leq \psi$ and $\psi \leq \phi$.

This solves your problem (2).

I don't fully understand your issue with (1). In $\mathsf{Set}$ we can identify subsets of $A$ with predicates on $A$. Namely we identify $P \subseteq A$ with the predicate $\mathbb{1}_P$ where $\mathbb{1}_P(a) = \begin{cases} \top & a \in P \\ \bot & a \not \in P \end{cases}$. Conversely, given a predicate $\phi(x)$ on $A$, we identify it with the subset $\{ a \mid \phi(a) \} \subseteq A$.

Generalizing to the world of categories, we don't have a way to get our hands on "subsets", only arrows. But we know that the subsets of $A$ are exactly the *images* of monomorphisms into $A$. After all, for any $P \subseteq A$, the inclusion $P \hookrightarrow A$ is a mono whose image is $P$. Conversely, for any mono $f : X \to A$, its image (which we can identify with $X$, up to isomorphism) is a subset of $A$.

This is what motivates the definition of subobject as monomorphisms into $A$. As you've correctly noticed, though, we overcount quite a bit when we do this (since we only *really* care about the image in $A$, not the mono itself). This is why we quotient by the equivalence relation outlined above.

(This is a slight fib -- it turns out we do often care about the monos themselves, especially when doing actual calculations. But I don't think this answer is a good place to get into such subtleties)

---

I hope this helps ^_^